# Unable to get value of the property 'submit': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

i have a iframe and form like this :

```
<iframe id="FileUploadFrame" name="FileUploadFrame" src="" style="display: none; border: 0; width: 0; height: 0;">
            <form id="FileUploadForm" name="FileUploadForm" accept-charset="utf-8"  target="FileUploadFrame" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="CIMtrek_Regional_WhseForm_FileUpload">
   </form>
</iframe>
```

and this is how i submit the form which in `iframe`

```
function fileUpload() {

    //var UploadForm = document.forms["FileUploadForm"];
    var UploadForm = global.forms["FileUploadForm"];

    alert("Form : "+typeof global.forms["FileUploadForm"]);
    alert("Form : "+typeof global.forms["FileUploadFrame"]);
    iframeId = document.getElementById("FileUploadFrame");


    // Add event...
    var eventHandler = function () {

        if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
        else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

        // Message from server...
        if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
            content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
        } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
            content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        } else if (iframeId.document) {
            content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
        }

        document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;
    }
    if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
    if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

    //alert('submitting form');
    //form.submit();
    //document.forms["FileUploadForm"].submit();
    alert(UploadForm.submit());
}
```

but i get the following exception when submitting the form :

```
Error: Unable to get value of the property 'submit': object is null or undefined
```

Please help me to find the problem and fix.

Best Regards

Comment: what's global.forms ? what does it do ? Is global a jsp or another html mark up in another file ?

Comment: var global = window.document, I have also tried the following `var UploadForm = document.forms["FileUploadForm"]` and `var UploadForm = document.forms["FileUploadForm"].submit()`

Comment: Where did you the javascript code place? Within or outside of the iframe?

Comment: it is a separate .js file where i have grouped all my java script methods and call them wherever needed.

Comment: @Anto I suggest using console.log instead of alert, and first try to see if global is set to anyting: console.log("global is now:",global) in IE you can start debugging by pressing F12 under script you can start debugging. Once you've done that console.log is supported (poorly) in IE

Comment: I suggest you go through this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353748/how-to-get-a-drop-down-selected-text-from-an-iframe This deals with this kind of iframe specific problem . Normally the problem is , it never finds the iframe, since the id is in parent, hence you need to gove parent.document.getElementByID(). You can also frameElement to get the iframe-id directly and then you can feed it to document.getElementbyD(frameElementID)--> This is much better and will always get the frameElement. Google to see how to use FrameElement .

Comment: Great comment, this is what i do : i have the file input in the parent form, i have to save the file selected in the parent form through this iframe, i should be like ajax call but actually it is not. in this case how to get the file selected in the parent form and assign the file to a file input in the form which is in iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get the `FileUploadForm` is:

```
iframeId = document.getElementById("FileUploadFrame");
//This is the trick
var ifrDoc = iframeId.contentDocument || iframeId.contentWindow.document;
var UploadForm = ifrDoc.getElementById("FileUploadForm");
```

Or you could have some code in the frame that sets a variable in parent to the form, but I wouldn't trust that method.

Source: [accessing a form that is in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478078/accessing-a-form-that-is-in-an-iframe)

---

**EDIT:**

Also, for get the upload form valid it needs to looks just like any other form except:

- the form tag must specify the `POST` method
- the form tag must specify an enctype of `multipart/form-data`
- the form must contain an `<input type=file>` element.

Comment: Previous one is gone and get this now `Error: TypeError: UploadForm is null`

Comment: @Anto: Check update, you need at least `<input type=file>` element inside the form

Comment: i have the file input in the parent form, i have to save the file selected in the parent form through this iframe, i should be like ajax call but actually it is not. in this case how to get the file selected in the parent form and assign the file to a file input in the form which is in iframe

Answer (score 1):

There is no `document.forms["FileUploadForm"]` cause your form is in an iframe. The `document` of the iframe is different from the `document` that your script is executed.

in your script add this line in the begining of the function

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('FileUploadFrame');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var UploadForm = innerDoc.forms["FileUploadForm"];
```